# Efficient way to do 3 left outer join in SQL for two tables with drop and rename some columns

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have below 2 tables ("Goal_n_Cat_Tab" and "Sales_Tab" with 50+ other columns for each table).

```sql
-- Goal_n_Cat_Tab
id1     ID          col1    Goal    col2    col3      Date      category
85643   G-00001     671     NaN     793     500   2021-06-13    J302022
85644   G-00001     5       56      8       89    2021-06-13    J302022
85644   G-00002     5       78      8       89    2021-06-14    J302022
8564312 G-00002     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   2021-06-13    J302022
8564314 G-00002     4       89      43      44    2021-06-14    J302022
85645   G-00001     60      73      610     60    2021-06-15    J302022
856442  G-00001     60      NaN     610     60    2021-06-15    J302022
85646   G-00001     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   2021-06-13    J302022
8564318 G-00001     0       NaN     0       5     2021-06-16    J302022
85647   G-00001     6       NaN     16      6     2021-06-13    J302020
85648   G-00002     3       NaN     23      3     2021-06-13    J302021
85649   G-00002     2       34      72      2     2021-06-13    J302021
85655   G-00002     4       NaN     48      4     2021-06-16    J302022
56731   G-00002     32      7       3       13    2021-05-23    J302021
34566   G-00003     3       84      28      12    2021-05-13    J302021
78931   G-00003     1       NaN     5       14    2021-03-26    J302022
78931   G-00003     23      5       3       98    2021-05-13    J302021
```

```sql
--Sales_Tab
RA      Oa      Goal    userid      Sa      Ai      ID          col1  col2  brand
0.96    5       771     85640       10      2       G-00001     1087  993     ABC
0.96    16      213     85844       32      38      G-00004     1200  8       cbc
7.25    15      42      35644       14      4       G-00002     173   8       ads
0.96    46      435     5564312     32      81      G-00002     1151  876     efn
0       3       NA      8564314     90      0       G-00002     1158  43      hae
8.7     51      822     856451      10      21      G-00002     1135  610     ABC
8.7     19      129     836442      32      3       G-00003     1169  610     cbc
1.48    45      732     36892       16      41      G-00001     1157  0       ads
0.96    46      542     8564318     7       81      G-00002     1134  0       efn
6.92    30      386     85647       67      14      G-00003     1084  146     hae
1.48    45      35      85648       16      41      G-00004     196   123     ABC
0.65    46      675     82749       7       81      G-00002     1104  172     cbc
8.7     30      772     85655       67      0       G-00002     1172  748     ads
0       56      NA      521731      17      0       G-00002     1104  43      efn
3.09    52.71   728     34566       32.44   33.31   G-00003     1139  278     hae
3.08    55.43   56      78931       32.79   33.87   G-00003     1184  128     ABC
3.07    58.14   679     78931       33.15   34.44   G-00003     1107  329     cbc
```

Here is what I'm going to do.
[image]

I want to do the 1st left outer join base on "id1" in "Goal_n_Cat_Tab"(LeftSide) and "userid" in "Sales_Tab"(rightSide). First I have to change "Goal" column name to "GoalwithBrand", "col1" to "col1Brand" and drop "col2" column in "Sales_Tab" then do the left outer join. I need all other columns to in result and is there a way to do this in one step or waht would be the Efficient way to do this since I have 50+ columns in my "Sales_Tab" table?

The 2nd left outer join should be base on the "ID" column. Same as above I want to change "Goal" column name to "GoalwithBrand", "col1" to "col1Brand" and drop "col2" column in "Sales_Tab" then do the left outer join.

The 3rd left outer join should be base on the "ID" column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hive is funny when it comes to efficiency. It really depends on the data itself and how it is stored in hdfs across many servers. It also depends on a lot of other things related to the number of resources the process has access to - so its hard to say for sure.

However I think you can write this all in 1 query, with each "output" being a subquery, that you can tailor to only have columns that you want to use in subsequent steps.

Once you hit a performance wall, it might be necessary to have each step write into an intermediate table, but I like to avoid that until it's absolutely necessary.